# Поиск и удаление мертвого js кода

Tags: javascript

Какие есть инструменты для поиска и удаления мертвого js кода? Есть ли возможность, помимо отдельных строк и блоков так же выявить не используемые обработчики событий и функции?

Comment: а *JSHint* не подходит?

Answer (score 3):

Если как отдельный инструмент, то **JSHint** Вам в помощь.

Если хотите прямо при разработке проверять используется ли код, то рекомендую один из продуктов **JetBrain**

В частности для web-разработки это **WebStorm** или **PhpStorm**